# Golang в библиотеке go-colly не работает их стандартный пример

Tags: golang

Есть библиотека go-colly (http://go-colly.org/) и есть пример работы с прокси по адресу http://go-colly.org/docs/examples/proxy_switcher/ .

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "log"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/proxy"
)

func main() {
    // Instantiate default collector
    c := colly.NewCollector(colly.AllowURLRevisit())

    // Rotate two socks5 proxies
    rp, err := proxy.RoundRobinProxySwitcher("socks5://127.0.0.1:1337", "socks5://127.0.0.1:1338")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.SetProxyFunc(rp)

    // Print the response
    c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        log.Printf("%s\n", bytes.Replace(r.Body, []byte("\n"), nil, -1))
    })

    // Fetch httpbin.org/ip five times
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        c.Visit("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    }
}
```

Который к сожалению ничего не выводит...
Если убрать код который отвечает за прокси, то всё работает... (есть вывод на экран информации)
Порты на моём компьютере не заняты...
При замене "socks5:/" на http, https, soks4 тоже код как надо не выполняется... (просто завершается без какого-то вывода на экран)
При использовании "реальных прокси" тоже код как надо не выполняется... (просто завершается без какого-то вывода на экран)

Если кто сталкивался с данной библиотекой подскажите в чём проблема!
Заранее вам благодарен за хороший ответ!

P.S. Я не программист, но иногда "кодю" для решения своих задачь...

Comment: У вас прокси рабочие? Вы браузером через них зайти можете?

Comment: Когда указывал внешние прокси (рабочие), тоже не работало... Я об этом писал - "При использовании "реальных прокси" тоже код как надо не выполняется... (просто завершается без какого-то вывода на экран)"

Comment: Как вы убедились, что эти "внешние" прокси рабочие? Вы же понимаете, что для того, чтобы пример заработал как есть, вам на локалхосте надо поставить и запустить два socks5 прокси (на соответствующих портах). А если вы используете внешний прокси, вам надо знать его тип (http/socks и т.д.) и порт, а не подставлять значения наобум.

Comment: Браузером проверял, указывая в настройках ip и порты...